# Receive UDP message, but go of if there is none

Tags: c, sockets, udp

I have a little problem, but haven't found a solution for it.

The problem seems to be quite simple:

I have a process. Within this process I want to check if there is a UDP message sent to the port I'm using. The whole send and receive thing is no problem, if there is a message sent. If there is no message sent, the process is waiting for a message and the program doesn't proceed until the next message is sent.

The question is how can I modify my code to let the process go on if there is no message.

My Code (standard code for receiving UDP messages):

```
if((nbrecv = recvfrom(s, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, 0, &remote, &len_remote)) == -1){
    fprintf(stderr, "failure!\n");
    exit(-1);
}

etc.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your options are as following:

1. Use `select()`, `poll()`, `epoll()`, etc. to wait for data instead of calling `recvfrom()` directly
2. Set your socket to be non-blocking by setting the `O_NONBLOCK` flag on the socket using `fcntl()`. This will make `recvfrom()` return immediately instead of blocking.
3. (not recommended) Set a receive timeout using the `SO_RCVTIMEO` socket option.